# Matplotlib change handles offset in legend

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to change the offset of the handles in the legend?

In 3 and 6, the marker is right on the dot and it would be better if it was a little further to the right so that the type of handle is better visible.
I played a little bit with the *markerscale* and the *handlelength*, but that obviously didn't change much.

How do I change the offset?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2])
y = np.array([1,3])

plt.plot(x, y, 'o-.',color='b', markersize=6,label='test',markeredgecolor="black")

plt.legend(markerscale=0.9,fontsize="medium",handlelength=3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the question. It would work with `handlelength=4`, but then, the box of the legend would be too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea using the [tuple handler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple) as described in the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html). For each line, there could be two entries, one with only the linestyle, and one with only the marker style. Setting `pad=0` leaves out the padding between the two parts, so the default `handlelength` still works. Probably a recent matplotlib version will be needed.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

for i, (ls, ms) in enumerate(zip([':', '--', '-.', ':', '--', '-.'], ['o', 'o', 'o', '^', 'v', 'd'])):
    plt.plot([0, 10], [i, i + 1], marker=ms, ls=ls, mec='black', label=i + 1,
             color='cornflowerblue' if i < 3 else 'orange')
plt.xlim(-0.5, 14)
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
new_handles = []
for h in handles:
    l = Line2D([], [])
    l.update_from(h)
    l.set_marker('')
    m = Line2D([], [])
    m.update_from(h)
    m.set_linestyle('')
    new_handles.append((l, m))
plt.legend(handles=new_handles, labels=labels,
           handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0)})
plt.show()
```

[image: legend with linestyle and marker style separated]

Another approach could be to experiment with a [custom line style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html).